# When to call super in method

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm having a problem understanding when to call a super in a overridden method. According to [this post](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.3/rules/java/android.html#CallSuperLast) it should be at the bottom, but my colleagues disagree.

What is your opinion on this topic?

Comment: according to the link you sent the are cases when first is better and when last is better.  No so much to do with opinion, but knowing what the code does.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is *depends*. The actual decision depends on what you are doing in the overridden method and also the *behavior expected by the base class* when you are overriding a particular method.

The documentation of the method you are overriding should provide the details of expected behavior while overriding. My personal preference call `super` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your overridden method is doing. If you're talking about a constructor, you have to call `super` first to ensure that the superclass is properly constructed before you go about setting its state. If it's another method, where you put the call depends on whether you're transforming the input parameters (`super` needs to go after that) or the return value (`super` goes before this).

The "post" you linked to is documentation for an automated code-audit tool, not a recommendation, and it has options for telling it that subclasses ought to be calling `super` at either the beginning or the end of their methods.

Comment: "as erarly as possible" may be misleading for constructor. `super()` NEEDS to be called at first line in constructor - always.

Comment: @PatrykRoszczyniała Edited. I forgot how much of a headache it is to pass transformed parameters to a super constructor...

Comment: @chrylis That’s not that hard. Expressions within the constructor arguments are allowed. Only if you need the result of an expression multiple times you need two constructors.

Answer (score -1):

My opinion is that the rules should comply with your coding standards.  If you can't agree, its a good sign it is not clear that you need to be checking this for your project.

Personally I have always put super calls at the start unless there as a very good reason.